Cannot send transaction using ethers.js on Ganache local chain
This is my deploy.js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x4052fa19bc76a24a63be5541b74538574311a264671facde218c15b665c59bf0",
    provider
  );

  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const nonceVal = await wallet.getTransactionCount();
  const tx = {
    nonce: nonceVal,
    value: "0", // Zero value, using BigNumber
    gasPrice: "20000000000", // 20 Gwei, using BigNumber
    gasLimit: "1000000", // 1 million gas, using BigNumber
    data: "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",
    chainId: 1337,
  }

  const sentTx = await provider.sendTransaction(tx);
  console.log("This is sent Tx: ", sentTx);
}
main();

I am trying to deploy my contract on my local ganache chain. However, when I try to run

node deploy.js

I am getting an error
 var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: invalid hexlify value (argument="value", value={"nonce":3,"value":"0","gasPrice":"20000000000","gasLimit":"1000000","data":"0x6080...0033","chainId":1337}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)}

What am I doing wrong over here?

Nvm, I fixed the issue.
I changed the tx to
const tx = {
    nonce: nonceVal,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0"),
    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("20", "gwei"),
    gasLimit: "3000000",
    data: "0x"+binary,
    chainId: 1337,
  };

Also, the sendTransaction method was to be called on wallet, not provider.
